# Angular2 output double parameter signature

Tags: typescript, parameter-passing, angular

Hello is there any way to pass two parameters in the output function from child component.

I want to call markQuestion from child component(answer-sheet) with (q_number, value) parameters but it gives me errors.

It works with one parameter.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4WHOT3

```
<answer-sheet *ngIf="current_question" [questions]="questions" [question] = "current_question" [answer_list]="answers"
    (markQuestion)="markQuestion($event)">
  </answer-sheet>
```

```
markQuestion(q_number:number, val:number){
    console.log(q_number , "numaralı soru cevap anahtarından ", val, " olarak isaretlendi" );
    //this.answers[q_number[0]] = {q_number[1]};
  }
```

```
export class Answers {
    // @Input() question: Object;
    @Output() markQuestion = new EventEmitter();

    @Input()
    answer_list;

    public question: Object;

    nextQuestionAnsweredButton(q_number,val){
        //There is an error at calling next function -> Supplied parameters do not match ..
        this.markQuestion.next(q_number,val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the Plunker be a fully working example? There seem to be parts missing.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an object

```
markQuestion.emit({q_number: q_number, value: value});
```

```
markQuestion(event:object){
    console.log(event.q_number , "numaralı soru cevap anahtarından ", event.val, " olarak isaretlendi" );
    //this.answers[event.q_number[0]] = {event.q_number[1]};
  }
```

Otherwise no you can't pass more parameters to an `@Output()`

Comment: Thank you ! Still it is weird that we cant pass two parameters. Maybe its weird because I don't know the "correct pattern"

Comment: You can send one event value. That's a common pattern. You can pack into that event whatever you want though.

Comment: how do you consume this event?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an object as argument

```
this.markQuestion.next({ no: q_number, value val});
```